# How to pass adapter text from model category?

Tags: android

I have text in the model. Must carry adapter. **public int cid = -1; public String category_name;** I want to transfer text only to the adapter. When I transfer some errors occur.I have tried to transfer from text model many times in adapter but I am not getting text i am new devloper How to fix this error

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.kannada.newspaper.india.R;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.activities.MainActivitym;
import com.kannada.newspaper.india.model.Category;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    private List<Category>  mensWears;


    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> mensWears) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mensWears = mensWears;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mensWears.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i,View view,ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final Category mensWear = mensWears.get(i);

        if (view == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_layout, null);
        }
        //For text
//        TextView prdId = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
//        prdId.setText(prdId.toString());



        

//        //For images
//        final ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
//        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mensWear.getItemName())){
//
////            Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrlFromServer+mensWear.category_image())
////                    .into(imageView);

        return view;
    }

}
```

**this model**

```
  public class Category implements Serializable {
      public int cid = -1;
        public String category_name;
        public String category_image;
        public String recipes_count;
        public Category(String name, String profession, int photo) {
        }
       public String getItemName() {
            return this.category_name;
        }
     public String category_image() {
            return this.category_image;
        }
        }
```

layout

```
<com.kannada.newspaper.india.utils.SquareFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ll_main"
android:padding="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/bg_google"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_roundiconimg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<!--            <ImageView-->
<!--                android:id="@+id/photo"-->
<!--                android:layout_width="60dp"-->
<!--                android:layout_height="60dp"-->
<!--                android:layout_gravity="center" />-->
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="347dp"
            android:layout_height="263dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sfprodisplayregular"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="@dimen/primeryText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</com.kannada.newspaper.india.utils.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Comment: To set the value in adapter's you have to get the value from the models not textview.

Comment: @Rahul Goswami  already add api just how to model string adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong you have to get the value from models not from the textview as in your sample you are doing below

```
TextView prdId = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
prdId.setText(prdId.toString());
```

you need to get the value from the model like below

```
prdId.setText(mensWears.get(i).getItemName());
```

Comment: image name   android:id="@+id/photo"